# How can I apply the decile cuts from one dataframe to another using R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, quantile

I have a dataframe (df1) and have calculated the deciles for each row using the following:

```
#create a function to calculate the deciles
decilefun <- function(x) as.integer(cut(x, unique(quantile(x, probs=0:10/10)), include.lowest=TRUE))

# convert df1 to matrix
mat1 <- as.matrix(df1)

#apply the function I created above to calculate deciles
df1_deciles <- apply(mat1, 1, decilefun)

#add the rownames back in
rownames(df1_deciles) <- row.names(df1) 

#convert to dataframe
df1_deciles <- as.data.frame(df1_deciles)

str(df1_deciles) # to show what the data looks like

#'data.frame':  157 obs. of  3321 variables:
# $ Variable1      : int  10 10 4 4 5 8 8 8 6 3 ...
# $ Variable2      : int  8 3 9 7 2 8 9 5 8 2 ...
# $ Variable3      : int  8 4 7 7 2 9 10 3 8 3 ...
```

I have another dataframe (df2) with the same rownames (Variable1, Variable2,etc...) but different number of columns.

I would like to use the same decile cuts which were used for df1 on this second dataframe but I'm not sure how to do it. I am actually not even sure how to determine/export what the cuts where on the original data which resulted on the df1_deciles dataframe I created. What I mean by this is, how do I export an object which tells me what range of values for Variable1 on df1 were assigned to a decile value = 1 or a decile value = 2, and so on.

I do not want to use the 'decilefun' function I created on df2, but instead want to use the variability and range information from df1.

This is my first question on the platform so I hope it is clear and I hope I have provided enough information. I have tried to find answers on the platform but have not found one. I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: `brks <- quantile(df1, probs=0:10/10)` should do it. Then use `cut(df2, breaks=brks)`. In the code the quantile function was wrapped in `unique()` which should be unnecessary unless there are very few values.

Comment: Thank you @dcarlson for your help. I found that `brks <- quantile(df1, probs=0:10/10)` only produces 11 values, but I have 3321 rows and don't get the appropriate values per row (I would like the decile cuts for each of the 3321 rows). I did find that the following does provide the decile breaks for each row `matrixStats=rowQuantiles(mat, probs=0:10/10)` (from the matrixStats package). Now I will use these breaks for df2.

Comment: I didn't notice that you were doing quantiles by row. `brks <- apply(df1, 1, function(x) quantile(df1, probs=0:10/10)` should also work.

Comment: Thanks. When I tried this, it produced the same decile cuts for each variable which was odd. When I tried to use the breaks from the matrixStats package, I kept getting the error "'breaks' are not unique". In the end I did the following: `df2_deciles = sapply(1:nrow(mat_1), function(i)   cut(mat_1[i,], unique(matrixStats_m[i,]), drop = FALSE, labels=FALSE, include.lowest=TRUE))` this produced the desired output - only thing is that I needed to add the rownames and colnames back in.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`:

```
##
#   create an artificial dataset with the structure you describe
#
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(Variable.1=rnorm(1000), variable.2=runif(1000), variable.3=rgamma(1000, scale=10, shape=5))
df1 <- t(df1)
##
#
df2 <- data.frame(Variable.1=rnorm(1000, -1), variable.2=runif(1000), variable.3=rgamma(1000, scale=20, shape=5))
df2 <- t(df2)
##
#   you start here
#   assumes df1 and df2 have structure described in problem
#   data in rows, not columns
#
library(data.table)
df1  <- as.data.table(t(df1))                                 # transpose: put data in columns
brks <- lapply(df1, quantile, probs=(0:10)/10, labels=FALSE)  # list of deciles for each row in df1
df2  <- as.data.table(df2, keep.rownames = TRUE)              # keep df2 data in rows: 1000 columns here
result <- df2[                                                # this does all the work
  , .(value= unlist(.SD), 
      decile=cut(unlist(.SD), breaks=c(-Inf, brks[[rn]], +Inf), labels=c('below', names(brks[[rn]])[2:11], 'above'))
      )
  , by=.(rn)]
result[, .N, keyby=.(rn, decile)]  # validate that result is reasonable
```

Applying deciles from one dataset to another has the nuance the some values in the new dataset might be outside the range of the original data. The test data here demonstrates this problem. `Variable.1` in `df2` has values lower than any in `df1`, and `variable.3` in `df2` has values larger than any in `df1`.

Comment: Thank you @jlhoward, yes I found the issue regarding the values outside the range of the breaks straight away. adding the -Inf and +Inf was very helpful. Thanks